# Embed Page Without JS or CSS Conflicts

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, codeigniter

I have question about posibility way to avoiding conflicts JS or CSS when I'm embed page from another site (Those both sites are on my own manage) without using iFrame or another framing solution.

i.e in my main page http://myfirstsite.com I want to show page from http://mysecondsite.com/page. I use same theme, javascript library, and css for both.

I already use $().load() and php file_get_contents() to show in my page (also using $.ajax). But it seems js library from http://mysecondpage.com/page doesn't work well.

Please see my captured image.

[image: Capture from myfirstsite.com]

[image: Capture from mysecondsite.com]

Note that why I'm using javascript load() because it will be a transaction request in the future.

Thanks for any advice and solution.

DK

Answer (score -1):

Javascript on a primary page will not actually conflict with the javascript in an embedded element so that being said the javascript is not your issue.

Comment: I see, but I really don't know why DataTables and another js library won't run in primary page. Any suggestion?